# QML: Conditionally set different properties of a property group

Tags: qt, qml

How can I conditionally set different properties of a property group in one go?

Example: Let's say that there is a context property `_context.condition` available. Given that value I would like to set different anchors for a qml item.

```
// Some item...
Rectangle {
    id: square
    width: 50
    height: 50

    // For simple properties this should work:
    color: { if (_context.condition) "blue"; else "red" }

    // But how to do it for complex properties like 'anchors'?
    // Note that I set different properties for different values of the condition.
    // Here is how I would do it, but this does not work:
    anchors: { 
        if (_context.condition) {
            // Anchors set 1:
            horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            bottom: parent.bottom
            bottomMargin: 20
        } else {
            // Anchors set 2:
            verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
            right: parent.right
            rightMargin: 20
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using QtQuick 2.0 in Qt 5.3. Thanks!

Comment: looks like horizontalCenter: _context.condition ? parent.horizontalCenter : 0  and so on

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that value 0 corresponds to "not set". I'll check that out. Cumbersome, but at least something. Thx!

Comment: actually, I'm not sure about this, just try :) maybe, you can assign 'undefined' instead of 0

Comment: At least it works for my example. Post a proper answer and you'll earn the credits! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try this (not tested):

```
anchors {
        horizontalCenter: _context.condition ? parent.horizontalCenter : undefined;
        bottom: _context.condition ? parent.bottom : undefined;
        bottomMargin: _context.condition ? 20 : undefined;
        verticalCenter: _context.condition ? undefined : parent.verticalCenter;    
        right: _context.condition ? undefined : parent.right;
        rightMargin: _context.condition ? undefined : 20;
        }
```

[Resetting properties values](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html#changing-anchors)

Also, according [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-var.html#change-notification-semantics) empty curly braces can be used to reset the value of property:

```
Item {
    property var first:  {}   // nothing = undefined
    property var second: {{}} // empty expression block = undefined
    property var third:  ({}) // empty object
}
```

Comment: I just found out that using '{}' instead of '0' is a more type-neutral way to say "undefined". Other than that, I'd accept your solution.

Comment: I have update link to the docs where it's described exact for anchors... please, check this http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html#changing-anchors

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Max Go answer, I've found that `null` is sometimes required instead of `{}`, etc.  Some QML properties resolve to C++ pointers under the hood, and null can equate "default" in such cases.